# how do I get the number of recorded complaints , and the number of checked and unchecked rows per each month in 2020 using laravel?

Tags: laravel, get, numbers, row, record

I use this table to store the customer complaints of a company and its name is complaint.
Can any specialist help me?

this is my query it only returns the total number of recorded rows per month, but I want the number of checked and unchecked complaints also.

```
Complaint::select( DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M') month"),DB::raw('count(id) as `num_id`'))->whereYear('created_at','2020')
                    ->groupBy('month')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

this is my table

| id | title | check | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 0 | 2020-02-14 07:09:15 | 2020-02-14 07:09:15 |
| 2 | student | 1 | 2020-02-14 07:09:15 | 2020-02-14 07:09:15 |
| 3 | teacher | 0 | 2020-02-18 07:09:15 | 2020-02-18 07:09:15 |
| 4 | staff | 0 | 2020-01-04 07:09:15 | 2020-01-04 07:09:15 |
| 5 | more | 1 | 2020-01-04 07:09:15 | 2020-01-04 07:09:15 |
| 6 | staff | 0 | 2021-01-04 07:09:15 | 2021-01-04 07:09:15 |
| 7 | more | 1 | 2021-01-04 07:09:15 | 2021-01-04 07:09:15 |
| 8 | staff | 0 | 2021-01-04 07:09:15 | 2021-01-04 07:09:15 |
| 9 | more | 1 | 2021-01-04 07:09:15 | 2021-01-04 07:09:15 |

the out put should be like this as sample

| month | total complaints | checked complaints | unchecked complaints |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jan | 100 | 50 | 50 |
| feb | 40 | 10 | 30 |
| jan | 100 | 50 | 50 |
| feb | 40 | 10 | 30 |
| jan | 100 | 50 | 50 |

Answer (score 1):

hi im not sure my code has correct syntax but im sure it will give you the correct idea to do what you want :
you should do something like this for every month:

```
$june_total = [];
    $june_checked = [];
    $june_unchecked = [];
    $all = Model::all();
    foreach ($all as $item){
        if ($item->created_at->format('M') == "june")
            array_push($june_total,$item);
        if ($item->check == 1)
        {
            array_push($june_checked,$item);
        }
            else{
                array_push($june_unchecked,$item); 
            }
    }
    $june_number = count($june_total);
    $june_checked_number = count($june_checked);
    $june_unchecked_number = count($june_unchecked);
```

you get all data from your model and for every month you have a foreach to check the month name (i wrote it for june) and in foreach if month is june i push the item to an array of june's records.

and also you check if item is cheched or not and push it in correct array again.

at the end you have 3 array for every month and you can get the count of them.

you should do this for all the months

i think the idea is working try it and good luck

Comment: thanks so much for your assist, but it doesn't give me the result as I want.